# Пунктуация в БСП

Tags: тире, бсп, бессоюзное

Почему между частями этого БСП ставится тире?

Так в Афинах власть царя сменилась властью знати – монархия сменилась аристократией.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Так в Афинах власть царя сменилась властью знати – монархия сменилась аристократией.***

1. Действительно, здесь надо поставить тире, так как отношения между частями БСП **присоединительные,** а не пояснительные.
2. Конечно, если подходить к правилам **формально**, то можно сослаться на такой пункт у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150): 2. Между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения двоеточие ставится обязательно, если в первой части имеются слова **так, таков, такой, одно** и т. п., конкретное содержание которых раскрывается во второй части: *Я это сделаю тАк: выкопаю подле самого камня большую яму…* (Л. Т.). Одно было несомнЕнно: назад он не вернётся (Т.)

Но это если подходить именно формально. Обратим внимание на то, что в примерах местоимение ТАК стоит в конце первой части, именно на нем понижается голос, а далее следует увеличенная пауза – предупреждение о последующем пояснении.

В предложении  «Одно было несомнЕнно: назад он не вернётся» понижение голоса делается на «несомненно». Во всех случаях мы ударением выделяем **ключевые слова,** связанные с пояснительной темой.

А если в приведенном примере поставить двоеточие, то что мы будем выделять для пояснения, **слово «знати»?** Это еще раз доказывает, что двоеточие здесь не ставится.

3. У нас же местоимение "так" относится к **предыдущим событиям** и имеет, вероятно, значение итога – "вот таким образом". Поэтому **нет здесь пояснения**, это добавочное сообщение, в котором первая часть повторяется, но **другими словами** (иначе говоря, монархия сменилась аристократией).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вообще говоря, при решении подобных задач надо именно анализировать **отношения** между частями БСП, причем делать это четко и однозначно, без колебаний от одной причины к другой.

Если есть **разъяснение** (а его здесь нет), да еще местоимение ТАК присутствует, то можно и к двоеточию склониться.

Что более **информативно**? Вряд ли дело в этом, информативность у сообщений одинаковая.

Подстановка **местоимения ЭТО** тоже не всегда приводит к положительным результатам, да и ни к чему оно здесь.

И зачем читать "образовайку", если есть наш родной официальный Розенталь, с ним надо разбираться.  О тире для обозначения **присоединительных отношений** говорится в п.8 и 9, но использовать эту информацию **напрямую не получается** – вот что нужно объяснять.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Answer (score 2):

*Так в Афинах власть царя сменилась властью знати – монархия сменилась аристократией.*

Тире можно объяснить **выводом** во 2 части или **присоединением**, когда можно подставить ЭТО.

*Так в Афинах власть царя сменилась властью знати – это монархия сменилась аристократией.*

Смотря что считать пояснением. Я думаю, вторая часть более информативна, важна, а в первой разъяснение:  монархия сменилась аристократией, это выразилось в том, что в Афинах власть царя сменилась властью знати.

Подробнее: https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/tire-v-bessoyuznom-slozhnom-predlozhenii.html